# Nuxt i18n does not load cookie language in root directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

Whenever I select a language in my application, it saves this parameter in the "lang" cookie, but accessing the root (http://localhost) without the language path (http://localhost/en) it loads the default language "pt", even the cookie set in another language "en" or "es". This is normal? Or is there any configuration for this type of situation?

```
[
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'es',
        file: 'es.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'pt',
        file: 'pt.js'
      }
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    parsePages: false,
    strategy: 'prefix',
    defaultLocale: 'pt',
    rootRedirect: 'pt',
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      cookieDomain: null,
      cookieKey: 'lang',
      alwaysRedirect: false,
      fallbackLocale: 'pt'
    },
  }
]
```

Method change lang:

```
changeLanguage(lang) {
        this.locale = lang
        this.$i18n.setLocale(lang)
        this.$moment.locale(lang);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to set the **alwaysRedirect** parameter to **true**, it forces the redirect by the cookie.

```
detectBrowserLanguage: {
  alwaysRedirect: true
},
```